# Reduce risk of the unexpected on a long-term portfolio

Tags: international, portfolio, diversification, long-term

I've been thinking recently what can I do to reduce risk on my long-term buy-and-hold portfolio.
When I say "risk", I'm talking about rare, unexpected but highly destructive events (think Taleb's Black Swans) - wars, global crises, political upheavals &c. &c.

My portfolio is diversfied on the following layers:

- Type: equities, bonds, REITs, cash, treasury bills and metallic gold
- Risk / return: S&P 500, developed markets, emerging markets, small-caps, gov't bonds, bank deposits
- Geography: USA, Europe, Asia
- Physical location of assets: Two countries in Europe and Russia (will probably open a new account somewhere else) - see also this question: [Where are my US/UK equities stored?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/where-are-my-us-uk-equities-stored)
- Banks and brokers: two separate brokers; cash in a large int'l bank; gov't treasury (will open a new brokerage account for foreign stocks and a local bank account for higher interest rate deposits)

As you can see, I'm quite well diversfied, but maybe I'm not doing enough or there's something that I might have missed. Tangible real estate? Land? Or something else that I haven't even thought about?

**UPDATE** I'm considering adding index options into my portfolio. The idea is to buy them cheap, deeply OTM (out-of-the-money) as a sort of *insurance* against huge market downfall.

Comment: Most of the steps that you have taken will do nothing to prevent tail risk losses.  Diversification helps one to avoid sector concentration risk but it does not mitigate the overall losses in  a large correction or bear market. It merely spreads the losses over many positions in the hope that some will not lose as much as the others - but most of them will  lose. In 2008-2009, many quality Dividend Aristocrats lost 50% or more with financials losing even more.

Comment: Well @BobBaerker, that's why I'm asking this question - what else shall I do to mitigate those risks?.. And my portfolio is not only diversified across sectors, it has positions all over the world, not just in the US...

Comment: Well @Alexander, how do you think that the steps that you have taken will protect you against  "rare, unexpected but HIGHLY DESTRUCTIVE events (think Taleb's Black Swans) - wars, global crises, political upheavals" ?

Comment: You need to cash out, that's the only way. You can't put your money into financial market and hope to never have drawbacks...

Comment: Hmmm.... discounting an an all-out nuclear war or ecological crisis (in that case I'd have to worry about food and shotgun shells, not portfolio... although I'd still have gold which could still have some value): imagine Trump making USA Union of Soviet Socialistic States of America, where everything is for a man, and my stock would be owned by The Man himself. I'd lose my US assets overnight, but there would still be Asia or Russia. There would be economic ripples but in the end that could benefit non-US economy (importers / investors fleeing to China).

Comment: And again, @BobBaerker, I'm not saying I'm the cleverest out there and have just figured out a bulletproof strategy. I wouldn't be asking this question here. If you think that I'm daft, please answer the question and elaborate why I'm stupid and what shall I do to be a bit less stupid. I would be grateful and appreciate that (as well as the other readers).

Comment: @YCN-, cash is not a good idea, it would be even more susceptible to catasrophic events. Metallic gold, on the other hand... Hmmm maybe I shall become Scrooge McDuck and take morning plunges in coins :)

Comment: @Alexander - I asked you a reasonable question (which you didn't answer) and you have  concluded from that question that I think  that you are daft and stupid.  How about a bit less hypersensitivity and attitude?  As for you original question, the short answer is that there is no bulletproof strategy.  Investing involves risk.  Risk and reward go hand in hand and in order to manage that, you have to take on more of one or give up some of the other.  Those choices can be complex and even  unacceptable to some.  Or, you just hope for the best and accept what comes you way (buy & hold).

Comment: In a global financial market collapse (aka 2008), cash will never lose what the financial markets do.  This would not be the case in third world countries with unstable currencies.

Comment: I didn't mean to be harsh @BobBaerker. It appears to me there's a misunderstanding. In my original question I say that I'm _not sure_ if my portfolio is good enough. Hence, I'm asking for advice. I don't really understand the point of your question...

Comment: As for the cash: I'm not a US citizen and unfortunately I've seen wads of cash being reduced into wads of toilet paper overnight... Of course cash is good for any portfolio (I've got around 13% now, to be reduced), but having 100% in cash doesn't sound like a healthy long-term strategy...

Comment: At this point, I'm confused as to what you are after. Your question asked about protecting against Black Swan events and cash (assuming the currency is stable)  protects against that.  But now you state that you don't like cash as a LT strategy and you think that your portfolio isn't "good enough".  Good enough for what?  To perform?  To protect?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  maybe the perfect portfolio that makes a lot of money in an up market and loses little in a down market?  There's no such thing.  You have to pick one.  More potential reward means more risk and vice versa..