# Withholding Agents in Canada

Tags: canada, bankruptcy

Hello everyone I had a quick question about Canadian banks. I have my investment accounts with my bank (big 5 bank). Legally when I buy the stocks they hold them for me, until I decide to sell them. My question is if the bank were forced into liquidation due to some unforeseen economic collapse or something crazy like that, would they be able to liquidate my shares in different companies to pay their own liabilities, or would they not be able to touch them under Canadian law?

Comment: If "withholding agent" in this context, in Canada, is roughly the same as a "nominee" (a company that holds shares on behalf of other people) then [my answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/94849/35567) to a different question may be of interest. I don't specifically know the Canadian position, but _usually_ such holdings will be "at arms length" from the bit of the company/bank that can go bankrupt.

Comment: That answer was extremely helpful, and definitely pointed me in the right direction. Cheers mate!